# WPF Create instances of controls defined in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a control defined in xaml with a fairly large number of properties set that is difficult to reproduce in code behind. Can I define the control in xaml and somehow create instances of it in the code behind?

Comment: Controls cannot be defined in XAML only, you will still have a code behind for it even though in some cases code behind may contain only `InitializeComponent()` line.

Comment: I understand that. But say for example I have a textbox defined in xaml. Can I create instances of the same textbox with the same properties in code?

Comment: Do you need to create it in code, or do you just need to be able to replicate those property values easily?  See my answer for a simple example of how to do the latter...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Another option is to create the control as a resource with the x:Shared="False" property if you want to get new instances on each resolution:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
  <Rectangle x:Key="MyControl" x:Shared="False" 
             ...
             />
</UserControl.Resources>
```

In code:

```
var myNewCtrl = this.FindResource("MyControl") as Rectangle;
// use control
```

Comment: Ooh, +1!  I never remember `x:Shared` :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can set any number of properties using a Xaml Style, and reapply that style - either directly to a separate instance of the control, or as the base for a different style.  The latter would allow you to specify your common properties but still, for example, have different visual settings for each control.

So, instead of trying to reproduce this:

```
<TextBlock Width="100" Height="40" FontSize="10" ClipToBounds="True" />
```

... define this in a shared resource file:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="myStyle">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="100" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="40" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="10" />
    <Setter Property="ClipToBounds" Value="True" />
</Style>
```

... and then use this in markup:

```
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource myStyle}" />
```

The same principle applies to any control and any set of properties.

Comment: Style is a really good solution. You can also create styles to target custom/user controls. You can only set DependencyProperties in styles.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered creating the control as a UserControl?

Comment: Not a bad idea, but it might be overkill if you just want to repeatedly set specific properties on a `TextBox`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can by using XamlReader: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlreader.aspx. Use the static method Load passing a stream containing your xaml markup. You obtain an object that is your control instance.